# Android: Tint Screen in MapView (Google Maps)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am using the following layout in my Activity which extends MapActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="My Google Maps Key"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

What I would like to achieve: When the user uses the map in the nighttime, the screen should be tinted with a dark color (black or dark blue). Since the MapView which fills the whole screen is derived from ViewGroup - I guess there is some way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could put the `MapView` in a `FrameLayout`, then apply [`android:foreground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#attr_android%3aforeground) on the `FrameLayout`, or something like that.

However, I suspect that this will not work very well. I suspect that what you *really* want is an alternate set of tiles, as is used by Google Navigation, where you have dark tiles with light text. I fear that your tint will simply make the map unreadable. But, perhaps you'll find a color and transparency level that achieves your aims.

Comment: +1 and accepted - What I used to get the desired effect is: As you suggested I embedded my MapView in a FrameLayout and added this attribute to the FrameLayout: android:foreground="#6408298A" (where 64 is the Alpha Channel and 08298A translates to a dark-blue) - this tints the map pretty good and makes it look night-timish. Streets are perfectly readable (I use Zoom Level 18 - so it's fairly close-up) - so all is well :)